# Why is there no view build in Sencha Touch cmd

Tags: sencha-touch-2, sencha-cmd

Using the following command:

```
sencha generate view user
```

I get the following error:

**[ERR]           Generate View is an ExtJS SDK specific command.**

Is there any reason why this doesn't work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you tap `sencha generate` you can see

```
Commands
  * app - Generates a starter application
  * controller - Generates a Controller for the current application
  * form - Generates a Form for the current application (Touch Specific)
  * model - Generates a Model for the current application
  * profile - Generates a Profile for the current application (Touch Specific)
  * theme - Generates a theme page for slice operations (ExtJS Specific)
  * view - Generates a View for the current application (ExtJS Specific
  * workspace - Initializes a multi-app workspace
```

So `sencha generate view ...` and `sencha generate theme ...` will only work with ExtJS

Comment: Weird how this functionality has been provided for ExtJS but not ST?